# PostgreSQL calling function with a null parameter

Tags: postgresql

I have a function that updates a row:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MyTable_UPDATE 
(
   _ID int,
   _Description text
) 
RETURNS bool
AS $$
DECLARE _OK boolean;

BEGIN
   _OK := false;
   UPDATE mytable SET
      Description = _Description 
   WHERE ID = _ID;
   _OK := true;

   RETURN _OK;  
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT;
```

When I call it with a value in description it works:

```
select MyTable_UPDATE(9, 'testing 123');
```

If I call it with a null value, it doesn't update, there is no error message and no value is returned:

```
select MyTable_UPDATE(9, null);
```

If I run an update query to set description = null, it works:

```
UPDATE mytable SET
   Description = null 
WHERE ID = 9;
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[From postgresql documentation on CREATE FUNCTION](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html)

> STRICT
>
> RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT or STRICT indicates that the function
> always returns null whenever any of its arguments are null. If this
> parameter is specified, the function is not executed when there are
> null arguments; instead a null result is assumed automatically.

In short, the function is not executed.

You have to remove the `STRICT` parameter to be able to pass a NULL value.

Answer (score 4):

You can also update the function to default to a value if `null` is supplied to allow for optional parameters.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MyTable_UPDATE 
(
   _ID int,
   _Description text default null
) 
...
```

Comment: Default null worked for me.  Now I can pass nothing in the call or a value.  Thanks

Comment: Useful, but it only works if you give also a default value to all arguments after it.